# Updated approach for max value using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

How to obtain the High of the day using pandas and make it update throughout the day as you can find it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lCLP.png) :

Note the highest price of the day is kept unchanged if the next high was lower than it. And it will be updated if a new high came in for each day from market open till close.

my code so far :

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.read_csv('*file location and name*', sep=",")

 df['Date_Modified'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + " " + df['Time'])    
 df.set_index('Date_Modified', inplace=True)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `groupby` with [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html), *i.e.* cumulative maximum:

```
df['High of the day'] = df.groupby('Date').High.cummax()
```

Comment: thanks a lot .. no words can express my gratitude to you

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are looking for the cumulative maximum, [`.cummax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html)

```
df["AlltimeHigh"] = df["High"].cummax()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking `cummax`.

MVCE:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2000,4000,50), columns=['Temp'])
df['Temp'].cummax()
```

Output:

```
0     2684
1     2684
2     3653
3     3653
4     3653
5     3653
6     3731
7     3731
8     3731
9     3747
10    3747
11    3778
12    3828
13    3828
14    3828
15    3828
16    3828
17    3828
18    3828
19    3828
20    3828
21    3828
22    3828
23    3828
24    3828
25    3828
26    3828
27    3828
28    3828
29    3828
30    3828
31    3940
32    3940
33    3940
34    3940
35    3940
36    3940
37    3940
38    3940
39    3940
40    3940
41    3940
42    3940
43    3940
44    3940
45    3940
46    3940
47    3940
48    3940
49    3985
Name: Temp, dtype: int32
```

Comment: you are amazing thank you